# Filter a list by the first letter(s)

Tags: javascript, indexof, startswith

I have a list of suburbs which I am filtering with the following. I works great but I'd like it to filter from the starting letters rather than matching any letters.

I feel like something like this should work but hasn't helped

`if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) === 0)`

`if (txtValue.toUpperCase().startsWith(filter))`

---

```
function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("mainNav");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="mainNav">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()" style="padding: 10px; background-color:#343434; border: 0px; color: white;">
                                          
  <?php include_once( 'suburbs.php' );?>
                  
</ul>
```

Comment: You can use String.startsWith https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith

Comment: Or even just change `> -1` to `=== 0`.

Comment: That's what brought me here. I've tried both of these but I get nothing returned any input in the search hides everything.

Comment: Show your html.

Comment: Added the list html. I can get this working correctly if I manually put in some <li> items  so it seems something with the php to import the values?

Comment: Worked it out there was a space before the Suburb name <li> SuburbName</li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be working fine for me.

```js
function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("mainNav");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().startsWith(filter)) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput" />

<div id="mainNav">
  <li>test1</li>
  <li>test2</li>
  <li>atcbjgjhg</li>
  <li>something</li>
</div>

<button onclick="filterFunction()">
  Filter
</button>
```